# Missing server side dependencies

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am getting an alert in Sharepoint Central Admin that **The SharePoint Health Analyzer has detected some critical issues.**

On checking, I found the alerts like:

[MissingSetupFile] File [Features\xxxx\xxxx\xxx] is referenced [1](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/06/removing-features-from-content-database.html) times in the database [PROD01_Content_xxxx], but exists only under Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 setup folder. Consider upgrading the feature/solution which contains this file to the latest version. One or more setup files are referenced in the database [PROD01_Content_xxxx], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these files.

[MissingFeature] Database [PROD01_Content_xxxx] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [f99f774c-6160-4bb6-8519-10e30b02d5b3]. The feature with Id f99f774c-6160-4bb6-8519-10e30b02d5b3 is referenced in the database [PROD01_Content_xxxx], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.

[MissingWebPart] WebPart class [a9bc1035-cf56-e003-8a4d-fff0bb3da148] (class [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchApplicationSystemStatus] from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced [1](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/06/removing-features-from-content-database.html) times in the database [PROD01_SharePoint_AdminContent], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database [PROD01_SharePoint_AdminContent], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts.

I followed the link:

http://get-spscripts.com/2011/06/removing-features-from-content-database.html

But unfortunately, on running the script, it shows the feature does not found.

One thing I would like to mention is: I've deployed the sharepoint 2010 wsp on 2013 version.Is this the reason for getting [MissingSetupFile] error?

What can I do? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Check if you are administrator. This shell command is only for [Missing Feature].

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to the first message that says "but exists only under Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 setup folder" . This means that you have deployed a 2010 solution into a 2013 farm. But is only installed to 14 hive. for the solution to work properly in the 2013 farm, it needs to be installed to the 15 hive also.

Here is the PowerShell that installs to both 14 and 15 hive.
Install-SPSolution -Identity 'your custom solution.wsp' -GACDeployment -CompatibilityLevel {14,15} -AllWebApplications –force

Answer (score 0):

The link below provides the solution.
Worked for me.

http://sharepointsoldiers.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/sharepoint-2013missing-serverside-dependencies/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While the link you've provided may answer the question, it's best to give some context when you post a link to make your answer more useful for others. [See here for more info on how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).