# Missing server side dependencies [MissingSetupFile] issue reported in Health Analyzer in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint

I am currently experiencing an issue where WebParts that were targeted originally at SharePoint 2010 and installed from a SharePoint 2010 wsp are raising “false” errors in some SharePoint 2013 deployments.

Please note: the WebParts are not related to Search or the Search Service Application (as per [Missing server side dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520618/missing-server-side-dependencies)).

The specific error can be seen below, but in brief:

```
Title:  Missing server side dependencies

Severity:  1 – Error

Category:  Configuration

Explanation: 

[MissingSetupFile] File [Features\xxx-WebParts\yyy\zzz.webpart] is referenced [1]
times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. 
Please install any feature/solution which contains this file. One or more setup 
files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the 
current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these files.
```

The WebParts are working without any issues and all seems deployed correctly.

I have recreated this issue in by performing the following,

```
1.  Web application exists with Compatibility range, 

    a.      MinCompatibilityLevel = 14

    b.      MaxCompatibilityLevel = 15

2.  WSP with WebPart is installed without any issues 
    (no reports in the health analyzer)

3.  I modify the Compatibility range in the SharePoint 
    Management Shell 

    a.      MinCompatibilityLevel = 15

    b.      MaxCompatibilityLevel = 15

4.  Run the Health check jobs.
5.  The error now presents itself within Central Administration
    under “Review problems and solutions”.

6.  To resolve the issue I thought to revert the compatibility 
    range back to, 

    a.      MinCompatibilityLevel = 14

    b.      MaxCompatibilityLevel = 15

7.  After changing, the errors remain.  
    Re-run health checks and the errors remain.
```

I have yet to figure out how to resolve the errors once they present themselves.

What can I do to resolve these errors such that they no longer appear in the “Review problems and solutions” within Central Administration?

---

Full Error Report here

```
Title   Missing server side dependencies. 
Severity    1 - Error 
Category    Configuration 

Explanation 

[MissingSetupFile] File [Features\xxx-WebParts\xxx\xxx.webpart] is referenced [1] 
times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. 
Please install any feature/solution which contains this file. One or more setup 
files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the 
current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these files.

[MissingSetupFile] File [Features\xxx-WebParts\xxx\xxx.webpart] is referenced [1] 
times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. 
Please install any feature/solution which contains this file. One or more setup 
files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the 
current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these files.

[MissingSetupFile] File [Features\xxx-WebParts\xxx\xxx.webpart] is referenced [1] 
times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. 
Please install any feature/solution which contains this file. One or more setup 
files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the 
current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these files.

[MissingSetupFile] File [Features\xxx-WebParts\xxx\xxx.webpart] is referenced [1] 
times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. 
Please install any feature/solution which contains this file. One or more setup 
files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the 
current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these files.

[MissingSetupFile] File [Features\xxx-WebParts\xxx\xxx.webpart] is referenced [1] 
times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. 
Please install any feature/solution which contains this file. One or more setup 
files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the 
current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these files.

[MissingSetupFile] File [Features\xxx-WebParts\xxx\xxx.webpart] is referenced [1] 
times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. 
Please install any feature/solution which contains this file. One or more setup 
files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the 
current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these files.

[MissingSetupFile] File [Features\xxx-WebParts\xxx\xxx.webpart] is referenced [1] 
times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. 
Please install any feature/solution which contains this file. One or more setup 
files are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the 
current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these files.

[MissingWebPart] WebPart class [ac91b8ba-f338-de25-0ac8-9a7c26ee7f1c] (class [xxx] 
from assembly [xxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=82d6cd9a489a599c]) 
is referenced [4] times in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the 
current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One 
or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but are not installed 
on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts.

Remedy   

For more information about this rule, see "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=142689".
```

---

Thanks.

Comment: what Web Part’s are you referring?  Custom or out of the box?

Comment: Custom.  They are not delivered with SharePoint.